# Pyinstaller failure: two quotes are automatically added at the end of Pathex in .spec file and make it fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, pyinstaller

I launch the .spec file that is below:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from os.path import join
sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['launch_ihm.py'],
             pathex=['C:/Users/anonymous/eclipse-workspace-tms/client_myprog/myprog/myprog/ihm/src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='launch_ihm',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Then for some reason I could not find, at some point, a double quote is systematically added to my pathex, making this:

```
'C:/Users/anonymous/eclipse-workspace-tms/client_myprog/myprog/myprog/ihm/src'
```

into this:

```
'C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog\\myprog\\ihm\\src\\""'
```

which is the reason for the failure.
(PS: I've tried different combinations with os.path.join and other slashes, I've tried to replace [] with None at some parts in the spec file)

Does anybody know what could be the reason for the failure?
Here below is the full log of error.
I could not find any similar error for pyinstaller on the web :(

Some more details, I am trying to pack into a .exe an eclipse project with many .py files.
I am referring pyinstaller to the py script that launches the IHM, hoping it could find the references and imports by itself. I am working with PyInstaller 3.6, Python 3.7.4 (conda).

Thanks and regards,

```
(base) PS C:\Users\anonymous\eclipse-workspace-tms\client_myprog\myprog\myprog\ihm\src> pyinstaller launch_ihm.spec
138 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
138 INFO: Python: 3.7.4 (conda)
139 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
140 INFO: UPX is not available.
147 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog',
 'C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog\\myprog\\ihm\\src']
148 INFO: checking Analysis
149 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
149 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
163 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
170 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
11031 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
11155 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
11172 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe
11496 INFO: Analyzing launch_ihm.py
16823 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
16827 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib'
31237 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   setuptools.extern.six.moves
33008 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
33012 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\anonymous\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
58474 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
78694 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   urllib3.packages.six.moves
197580 INFO: Processing module hooks...
197581 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-babel.py"...
197831 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-certifi.py"...
197835 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-cryptography.py"...
198403 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
198407 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docutils.py"...
204153 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-docx.py"...
204184 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
204358 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-importlib_metadata.py"...
204363 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-IPython.py"...
205000 INFO: Excluding import 'matplotlib'
205005 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib from module IPython.core.pylabtools
205006 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.pyplot from module IPython.core.pylabtools
205006 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib.figure from module IPython.core.pylabtools
205006 INFO:   Removing import of matplotlib._pylab_helpers from module IPython.core.pylabtools
205008 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
205013 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module IPython.lib.clipboard
205014 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
205019 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205019 INFO: Excluding import 'gtk'
205025 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
205030 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205030 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
205036 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205036 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtWidgets from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205036 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205036 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtSvg from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205036 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module IPython.external.qt_loaders
205037 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jedi.py"...
205693 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jinja2.py"...
205710 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-jsonschema.py"...
205728 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
205737 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lxml.etree.py"...
205739 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.backends.py"...
206945 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    The GTK3 backends require PyGObject
207653 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    The GTK3 backends require PyGObject
208344 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name '_macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py)
209736 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": added
210508 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
211330 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": added
212109 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
212936 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": added
213655 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
214359 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": added
215105 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
215780 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
216322 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
216861 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
    No module named 'wx'
217432 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
217969 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": added
218681 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
219367 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
219935 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
220493 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
221162 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
222310 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-matplotlib.py"...
222836 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbconvert.py"...
222911 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-nbformat.py"...
222935 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-notebook.py"...
228239 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
228405 INFO: MKL libraries found when importing numpy. Adding MKL to binaries
228415 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.py"...
228416 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-openpyxl.py"...
228456 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pandas.py"...
230519 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.Image.py"...
231323 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.py"...
231330 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
231332 INFO:   Removing import of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk
231333 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
231336 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt4 from module PIL.ImageQt
231337 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
231338 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
231342 INFO:   Removing import of PySide from module PIL.ImageQt
231343 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
231346 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtCore from module PIL.ImageQt
231346 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5.QtGui from module PIL.ImageQt
231347 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py"...
231351 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
231354 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
231354 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
233477 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
234331 INFO: Excluding import '__main__'
234334 INFO:   Removing import of __main__ from module pkg_resources
234334 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pycparser.py"...
234339 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
234340 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pygments.py"...
235958 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
236210 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
236211 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
236312 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
236518 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtSvg.py"...
236876 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
237149 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytest.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "launch_ihm.spec", line 19, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 422, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 311, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 417, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 384, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 797, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 407, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 907, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 732, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-pytest.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 24, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _pytest._code
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pluggy
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\Users\anonymous\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte: 'C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog\\myprog\\ihm\\src\\""'
```

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem was the following:
 - Another inhouse module was being called by the module I wanted to compile into an executable. Let's call this another module inhouse
 - I moved the launcher file into a folder common to inhouse and myprogram
 - I inserted into the script launch_ihm
   sys.path.insert(0, dir_myprogram)
   sys.path.insert(0, dir_inhouse)
 - I built the new spec file from the common folder
 - I run pyinstaller from the common folder
And it has solved this specific problem

I also want to thank  @jizhihaoSAMA for the active discussion in the comments that has helped the thinking

Comment: I also had the problem a second time, and this time the reinstallation of anaconda solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `/`. try to use `\\` and pack it again.

And why do you add `""` in the end?
change your code to

```
pathex=['C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog\\myprog\\ihm\\src']
```

PS.(`src` folder should be your root path of your python project.if not,please use my format and change it to your root path of your python project).

Comment: Thank you for answering jizhihao, however, there are some misunderstandings:
1- As I have tried to communicate in my question, I am not adding the "" in the end, this is pyinstaller that is adding it at some point for some reason I could not find. You may want to look for the log details
2- As I have also tried to communicate in my question, I have tried several solutions to write the pathex in other ways in the spec file, including the one that you suggest, but the problem is exactly the same

Comment: @MattDnv You say that you try this,``'C:/Users/anonymous/eclipse-workspace-tms/client_myprog/myprog/myprog/ihm/src'``,OK.Do you update your pyinstaller?

Comment: This is my .spec file:``pathex=['E:\\work\\Compile\\python\\OCR']``.I can pack it normally.

Comment: Hi Jizhihao, thanks for your ideas
 1- I have the last version of Pyinstaller, all the versions are given in the question (PyInstaller 3.6, Python 3.7.4 (conda))
 2- With this kind of Pathex, I cannot pack it normally either, the problem most likely comes from somewhere else than the pathex variable but I don't know where it comes from

Comment: @MattDnv I compare you file to my file.The difference between them is ``import sys
+from os.path import join+
sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)``,You can try to delete them and try again.

Comment: @MattDnv Or I think you can copy your python project folder to another folder(the folder's name don't have ``-`` and ``_``).

Comment: Thanks a lot you for your active cooperation Jizhihao.
Here are my two answers to your comments:
1 - I have deleted   `import join`, it has not changed anything
2 - `import sys` and  `sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)` cannot be deleted, otherwise another bug occurs at an earlier point of time
-- To be followed

Comment: 3 - I have now moved the launch_ihm.py folder to the main project folder and changed the command and pathex consequently, I still have the same error:
3a - `pathex=['C:\\Users\\anonymous\\eclipse-workspace-tms\\client_myprog\\myprog\\myprog']`
3b - `C:\Users\anonymous\eclipse-workspace-tms\client_myprog\myprog\myprog\> pyinstaller launch_ihm.spec`

Comment: @MattDnv I have no idea but two suggestions.Firstly, Copy it to a folder whose name without ``-`` and ``_``(For example,``D:\\Work\\Python``).Secondly, Use ``pyinstaller xx.py`` directly or ``pyi-makespec xx.py`` to generate a new spec file again.

Comment: "Firstly, Copy it to a folder whose name without - and _" Thank you for this idea jizhiao, I've just tried it, but it doesen't work either unfortunately :( Each time I am generating with `pyi-makespec -F launch_ihm.py` too

Comment: And using either `pyi-makespec -F launch_ihm.py` or `pyi-makespec  launch_ihm.py` doesn't change anything either

Comment: @MattDnv Have you tried to use ``pyinstaller -F xx.py`` directly?

Comment: ``-F`` or not,You don't know it if you only see the spec file.

Comment: " Have you tried to use pyinstaller -F xx.py" Thank you for the idea, but if i do this i get another earlier bug, at some point of time, i need to copy paste the following lines into the spec file: `import sys` and `sys.setrecursionlimit(9000)`

Comment: I have just realized that the programs are calling another inhouse made module. I have used the executable builder with a python script in a folder common to the program I want to execute and the other module. At least I was able to build an executable and the error message was not reproduced, however the executable doesn't work. This means that this problem might have been sold but it is not sure yet.

Comment: @MattDnv Just use debug mode.

Comment: I am using the debug mode to build the executable with pyinstaller. The executable is closing immediately now. Maybe the problems are related. I keep on investigating

Comment: Now i get another error (module not found error) , which means that most probably the bug has been resolved by running the pyinstall in a folder common to the program i want to run and the another inhouse py module (and inserting them in the syspath inside the script). I wait that my program runs well completely and then I will make a full answer